# Is there a library or an api to store files into one big file?

Tags: java, c++, windows, file, api

i am wondering is there a library to pack all of your configuration files or etc. and put 
them in to one big file for you to access programmatically.

I know there exists SQLite but i dont want to use an sql engine, i just need an api which gives me file handles inside a big file and manages this big file for efficiency or corruption.

Languages preferred are Java, c, c++ and os is windows.

thx

Comment: I imagine `java.util.jar` would cover Java, and there may be a similar abstraction for C++. Does that meet the requirements?

Comment: SQLite is not a bad idea either, once you get over having to use SQL. It's efficient and reistent to corruption, and can be accessed safely by concurrent processes (on the same machine).

Comment: a cross language solution will be more better.i think zip can meet my requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use zip files.  All of those languages support reading them, and they are ubiquitous so desktop tools to easily look inside them are readily available.

Answer (score 1):

You could, perhaps, use a zip file. It's not a perfect format, but it's ubiquitous, and readily accessed from Java and C.

Answer (score 1):

BerkeleyDB is a flatfile key/value store that could be just what you need.  Keys are char* and you store your value as a void*.  You could treat this as a filename (key)/ file contents (value) pair.  There is a native API for BerkeleyDB for most modern languages.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is very much like [COM Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with chubbard about using Zip files. But I really like using [PhysicsFS](http://icculus.org/physfs/) (not a physics library) for accessing Zips like this. It makes working with zip files, directories, and such much easier.

Granted, Zip files don't really handle corruption very well.

Answer (score 0):

If all the configuration files are in xml format, you could import all of them in one xml file and use it.